# How do I assign a pointer to a string and modify it using said pointer?

Tags: c, string, pointers, malloc, structure

Say I had an array of structures with them being defined as

```
typedef struct myS
{
    int content;
    char *string;
} myT;
```

I'd like to change the value of the 0th element's string through a pointer so as not to have to access it through the structure directly.

What I've done was the following:

```
myT *tArray;
char **pString;

tArray = malloc(sizeof(myT));
tArray[0].string = "hello";
pString = malloc(sizeof(char *));
*pString = tArray[0].string;
```

What I'd expected to happen was that now that `pString` is pointing towards `tArray[0].string`, any changes applied to `tArray[0].string` should reflect on `*pString`, after all, that's what happens with `int` and `*int`. However, after testing, this is what I got:

```
printf("%s %s ", tArray[0].string, *pString);
tArray[0].string = "hi";
printf("%s %s", tArray[0].string, *pString);
```

```
>hello hello hi hello
```

I don't really understand why `pString` is still pointing towards `"hello"` here.

Is there a way to modify the value of the structure through another variable?

Comment: First things first: enable all warnings on the compiler, and then fix them.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError  Well, it seems I forgot to allocate memory for myT. So what now?

Comment: You've not modified `*pString` (what `pString` is pointing to), and if you tried you would likely get a crash as `tArray[0].string` points to a literal, which you can't write to. You would need to copy it somewhere else first. `tArray[0].string = "hi";` assigns another literal pointer to `tArray[0].string` - it does not alter the original.

Comment: And you seem to want to use pString to access whatever `tArray[0].string` points to at any time, so you want it to point to tArray[0].string, not another pointer that at one time pointed to the same thing. [Perhaps something like this](https://godbolt.org/z/ozbcfb75b), though heed @500-InternalServerError's critically vital comment about not modifying string literals.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError OK if I've understood correctly, `hello` has its own address and at first `.string` points towards it. Then, by assigning `pString = .string` now both of them are pointing towards `hello` rather than `pString` pointing towards `.string` poiting towards `"hello"`? And after pointing `.string` towards `"hi"`, it doesn't change where `pString` is pointing? If so, then you've answered my question. As for the solution, I've tried using `malloc` and `strcpy` on `.string` and it seems that `pString` and `.string` are successfully pointing towards the same value now so thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you expect the following results?

```
hello hello hi hi
```

Then, set the address of `.string` to `pString` as follows:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  typedef struct myS
  {
      int content;
      char *string;
  } myT;
  myT *tArray;
  char **pString;

  tArray = malloc(sizeof(myT));
  tArray[0].string = "hello";
  //pString = malloc(sizeof(char *));
  //*pString = tArray[0].string;
  pString = &tArray[0].string;

  printf("%s %s ", tArray[0].string, *pString);
  tArray[0].string = "hi";
  printf("%s %s", tArray[0].string, *pString);

  return 0;
}
```